# Add additional projects to blogdown academic themed website

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm trying to add more project cards onto my blogdown: http://insidethetv.rbind.io/

To make the first project card, I found the index.md by clicking: content -> project -> external-project -> index.md

Then, I changed the information to:

```
---
date: "2016-04-27T00:00:00Z"
external_link: https://howiebaik.shinyapps.io/medium-claps-predictor/
image:
  caption: Medium Claps
  focal_point: Smart
summary: Predict Medium Claps
tags:
- Shiny app
title: Medium Clap Predictor App
---
```

And changed featured.jpg to a Medium clap.

However, this is great for adding one project. How can I add additional project cards?

Thank you

Comment: Add one directory with suitable `index.md` per project in `content/project`. You might also rename `external-project` to something less generic.

Comment: https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/managing-content/#create-a-project